# How do I resolve a sign-in "recursion" in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I have already signed into Chrome, but still it prompts me to sign in again.  How do I resolve this?

[image]

As you can see my Google+ is synched, yet still I need to sign in. I tried many times but every time I sign in, the prompt to do so keeps coming back.

Comment: Signing into Google+ and Chrome are two separate things. Does it say there is a problem signing you in to Chrome?

Comment: @fooot No there is no problem signing-in. Every time I signed up the yellow bar comes back.

Comment: The Google page says the orange means there is an error, are you sure it doesn't say anything? https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1181420?hl=en